# couchdb ; how get documents directly in first level of json, and not grouped inside value - viewWithList

Tags: json, couchdb, rxjs5

I have a design document: 'accounts',and the view: 'accounts-view'

the view's content is:

```
function (doc) {
  emit( doc._id, doc);
}
```

And my code in express is:

```
db.view('accounts', 'accounts-view', function(err, body) {
    if (err) throw error;
    res.json(body.rows);
});
```

Result is:

```
[
  {
    "id": "8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b0580065af",
    "key": "8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b0580065af",
    "value": {
      "_id": "8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b0580065af",
      "_rev": "1-37eb3e76e4715e9a4fc8930470cc4ca3",
      "type": "accounts",
      "lastname": "Kitchen",
      "firstname": "Peter"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b058006e3c",
    "key": "8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b058006e3c",
    "value": {
      "_id": "8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b058006e3c",
      "_rev": "1-bcab94bb253c83b4951a787c253896f5",
      "type": "accounts",
      "lastname": "Kolner",
      "firstname": "John"
    }
  }
]
```

How i can get just something like this: ( just printing all is inside value for every row)

```
[
  {
     "_id": "8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b0580065af",
      "_rev": "1-37eb3e76e4715e9a4fc8930470cc4ca3",
      "type": "accounts",
      "lastname": "Kitchen",
      "firstname": "Peter"

  },
  {

      "_id": "8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b058006e3c",
      "_rev": "1-bcab94bb253c83b4951a787c253896f5",
      "type": "accounts",
      "lastname": "Kolner",
      "firstname": "John"

  }
]
```

UPDATE:

I've follow Domonique's suggestions ; and now I have a new view, that emit just the id (so i can save space on disk and retrive de doc with the parameter "include_docs=true" on the view):

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type && doc.type=='accounts') {
    emit( doc._id);
  }
}
```

and a new list:

```
function(head, req) {
  provides('json', function() {
    var results = [];
    while (row = getRow()) {
      //results.push(row.value);
      results.push(row.doc);
    }
    send(JSON.stringify(results));
  });
}
```

Finally i get the records with:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/crm/_design/crmapp/_list/accounts-list/accounts-view?include_docs=true
```

and the result is:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b0580065af",
    "_rev": "1-37eb3e76e4715e9a4fc8930470cc4ca3",
    "type": "accounts",
    "lastname": "Kitchen",
    "firstname": "Peter"
  },
  {
    "_id": "8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b058006e3c",
    "_rev": "1-bcab94bb253c83b4951a787c253896f5",
    "type": "accounts",
    "lastname": "Kolner",
    "firstname": "John"
  },
  {
    "_id": "8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b058008e9a",
    "_rev": "1-86078f00be82b97499a0f52488cefbbf",
    "lastname": "Tower",
    "firstname": "George",
    "type": "accounts"
  }
]
```

my app node express updated:

```
db.viewWithList('crmapp', 'accounts-view','accounts-list', {"include_docs":"true"} , function(err, body) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(body);
});
```

with this list , I don't need more reduce it on express project, it's ok ?
How to udate my list or view to get by id ? it'not working just adding id on the url ; like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/crm/_design/crmapp/_list/accounts-list/accounts-view?include_docs=true&_id=8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b058006e3c
```

I get all the records and not the only one by id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question here, you should simply [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array and only include the `value` portion:

```
db.view('accounts', 'accounts-view', function(err, body) {
  if (err) throw error;
  res.json(body.rows.map(function (row) {
    return row.value;
  }));
});
```

Since it's apparent you are new to CouchDB, I'll also give you some advice regarding views. First, the view you've created is actually just a duplicate of the system view `_all_docs`, so you should just use that instead rather than creating your own view. (especially since you've effectively created a duplicate on disk)

However, it is probably pretty likely that as you get further along in your application, you'll be using real views that partition documents differently depending on the query. As such, you should *not* emit your entire document (ie: `doc`) in your view function. By doing this, you are effectively duplicating that document on disk, since it will be represented in your database, as well as the view index.

The recommended starting point is to simply leave out the 2nd argument of your emit.

```
function (doc) {
  emit(doc._id);
}
```

When you query the view, you can simply add `include_docs=true` to the URL and your view will look something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b0580065af",
    "key": "8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b0580065af",
    "value": null,
    "doc": {
      "_id": "8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b0580065af",
      "_rev": "1-37eb3e76e4715e9a4fc8930470cc4ca3",
      "type": "accounts",
      "lastname": "Kitchen",
      "firstname": "Peter"
    }
  }
  // ...
]
```

Then, you can retrieve the `doc` instead of `value` to achieve the same result much more efficiently.

Comment: it's smart  including  just emit(doc._id) , so i save disk space ? i did not read that in tutorials but it's a good idea

Comment: i've used couchapp and then  i've this function on the server ( it's more efficient to do the map on the node app?? ) : function(head, req) {
  provides('json', function() {
    var results = [];
    while (row = getRow()) {
      results.push(row.value);
    }
    send(JSON.stringify(results));
  });
}

Comment: i did just emit(doc._id) but i'm yet i'm getting lot of fields: {
 "id": "8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b058006e3c",
 "key": "8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b058006e3c",
 "value": null,
 "_id": "8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b058006e3c"
} , how i have just the id field ?

Comment: Don't forget `include_docs=true`, as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: i did it, and works well, but i'm using a list with the view, it's better like this than reduce it on node app ?  please look at my answer updated